# Rotate a view when navigation drawer slides

Tags: android

This is how I am trying to rotate ImageView (Menu Button) on drawer slides. I am using a custom ImageView set an angle to rotate from drawer slides offset and invalidate the view. My question is whether it is a better solution or not? If not please suggest me some better alternate solution for my problem.

**MenuButton.java**

```
public class MenuButton extends ImageView {

    public int angle = 0;
    public MenuButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MenuButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(angle, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

}
```

and in `DrawerListener` implementation a set the angle to ImageButton object as

```
 @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

            float angle = slideOffset * 360;
            menuButton.angle = (int) angle;
            menuButton.invalidate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

    }
```

Comment: did you find the correct solution? pls share, as I am also struggling with same. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since API level 11, you can use [setRotation(angle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29)

BTW, you should [animate rotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html) when drawer slides.